# objective-C instance variable to keep track of first time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I need to do an operation just once when my app is launched the first time.  I fit success no need to repeat during subsequent launches.

I am using the standard approach of using a property and setting it to YES the first time app is launched and initialization code succeeds.

I have a few Qs that will help me improve my Objective-C understanding and hence would greatly appreciate the experts inputs.

1. I am assuming I need to set the property attribute to strong since the memory associated with the variable may be released if it is set to weak.  Is this correct?
2. Setting it to strong is preventing me from using BOOL type (the error indicated I need to use an object)

   - To workaround, the property type is set to NSNumber and I am setting it to @(YES) after routine completes and comparing it against @(YES) to see if initialization needs to be done at app launch.

IS the above approach/understanding correct?  If no, I'd appreciate pointers to what is wrong.  Also, even if above will work, but there is a more elegant way to do what I'm trying to do, please do let me know.

Comment: Hi, I want to know in First Point that when the memory associated with the Property is released, when you set it to weak ?

Comment: 2nd Point is correct

Comment: The main point is that When your memory is released.?

Comment: When your app will be closed, all memory associated with its instance variables will be lost !!! yes

Comment: So, straight forward answer is to your question is to use NSUserDefaults. If you want to discuss about How Strong and weak, and assign work It is different topic.Yes It is also important topic. But In your case nothing work then NSUserDefaults.

Comment: What is the meaning of "I fit success no need to repeat during subsequent launches." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I am assuming I need to set the property attribute to strong since the memory associated with the variable may be released if it is set to weak. Is this correct?

Sorry, **NO**.

An automatic property (one where you do not write your own setter and getter methods) lifetime & memory behaviour is the same as for *instance variables*. So:

1. The *lifetime* of the property is the same as the object instance it belongs to - the *storage* for the property is created as part of creating the object instance, and it is destroyed as part of destroying the instance.
2. For properties with *primitive type*; e.g. `int`, `double`, `BOOL`, `NSInteger` etc.; the value is stored directly in the property and there is no other memory management required.
3. For properties of *object reference type*; e.g. `NSArray *`, `NSNumber *`, etc.; the value stored in the property is a reference to an object. In this case the property may be marked as `strong`, `weak`, etc. so that ARC knows how to manage the lifetime of the *referenced* object (not the lifetime of the property).

So in your case with a `BOOL` property you do not need `strong`, `weak`, etc. - they would be meaningless for such a property. You *do not* convert your property to `NSNumber *` just so you can make it `strong`, there is no need to do this.

> I am using the standard approach of using a property and setting it to YES the first time app is launched and initialization code succeeds

For your particular application this is not the standard approach, what you need is a value which will persist between application launches, and for that you can user `NSUserDefaults`. In particular you need the methods `boolForKey:` to retrieve the current value, and `setBool:forKey:` to set the value.

When you first run your application you will (obviously!) not yet have written any value to `NSUserDefaults`. In this situation, where a value for a key has not yet been written, the method `boolForKey:` will return `NO`. So all your application needs to do to run code once on the first run is to read the key you will use for this, say `@"firstRunDone"`, and if the result is `NO` to execute the first-run code and then set the key value to `YES`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You're right about using `strong` modifier. `strong` only applies to `NSObject`-derived types (ie types derived from `NSObject`, which implies it has to be a class type), so you are correct about using `NSNumber` instead of `BOOL`.

However, if you need to run only the **first time** the app launches, you need to store it in a more persitent place, e.g. `NSUserDefaults`; an ivar/property will be gone as soon as the app is terminated, and takes default value when the app launches again. `NSUserDefaults` also supports primitive `BOOL` type, no need to worry about memory policy.

Answer (score -1):

The strong and weak property attributes are to do with Automatic Reference Counting within Objective-C, i.e., iOS uses this to know when an object is still being used and should be kept in memory. The "strong" attribute will increment the reference count of the object in question, preventing the memory associated with the variable being released; so yes you are correct when you say that you need to set the property to strong.

With weak properties, the referenced object may be released while the property holds the reference. This is a helpful explanation of memory leaks & properties etc: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-strong-retain-nonatomic-etc-in-the-Objective-C-iOS-property

To use the BOOL type, you do indeed need to use an object. BOOL is an intrinsic type and so cannot have an explicit value; there needs to be something there to *be* true or false (or yes or no, in this case).

I hope this has helped your understanding a bit :) There are other similar SO posts dealing with BOOL properties; they might be helpful too. Good luck!